# Trying to use OS Translator plugin and can't find ogr2ogr.exe

Tags: plugins, ogr2ogr

I have installed the OS Translator plugin from the Faunalia Repository but when I try to use the plugin I get a "Can't find ogr2ogr[.exe], can't continue" error message. I have tried reinstalling the complete GDAL package but to no obvious effect.

I am running QGIS on a MacBook Pro with an up to date version 10.8 of OS X and installed packages from the KingChaos site.

Any ideas please?

Update.
I have managed to find the ogr2ogr.exe file and, as it exists, that suggests that the installation of the the GDAL Framework does not properly edit the PATH to the file. I'm still trying to re-learn some basic bash shell commands under the OS X Mountain Lion environment to make the necessary changes to PATH.

Comment: Update. Found out that I can run the ogr2ogr plugin from the command line now I have PATH set correctly. As I can do this I don't need to run the plugin from the Mac GUI so the PATH conundrum in that environment is no longer a problem.  I would still like to 'fix' it though as it has become a bit of a technical challenge.